# Transfer speed over wifi and 3G within the same room

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, wifi, android-wifi

If two or more mobile devices are in the same room and using wifi and to transfer data between each other and they both get their wifi from the same source, is the speed usually higher than if it were communicating with an external server, say EC2? Is it faster because the data path is source -> wifi provider -> destination instead of source -> a bunch of modems that transmit from one to the next -> server?

What about through 3G? If the devices are in the same room (and hence accessing the same tower), is it faster than if the devices were, say, in different cities?

EDIT: To make it clear here's the comparisons:

Wifi -> speed while communicating between two devices in same room vs speed while communicating between two devices in different cities.

3G -> same comparison (devices in same room vs 2 devices in different cities)

I'm NOT trying to compare Wifi vs 3G. Sorry for the confusing wording.

Comment: both 3G and WiFi depend on signal strength & bandwidth usage

Comment: assuming both devices have the same signal strength, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Wifi speed in the same room would operate at the maximum connection speed of the signal allowed, split between the number of active devices. This would generally be considered quite high although not as high as a network cabled series of devices.

When sending a file over wifi to a remote host, the exchange goes from your computer through a series of hops on its route to the destination so the initial wifi speed is only in transferring the file to the server. It is then server dependent on how fast it transfers between computers, since they can't have a direct wifi connection.

3G locally is faster than between cities because, as you say, it interacts with the local host tower rather than then moving beyond that to the next tower and so forth. 3G would be slower than wifi initially, but when transferring files over city wide or regional distances then Wifi will only be faster on the initial transit of the file. After that it comes down to the network infrastructure in place, and as I mentioned in the first attempt - that can vary on country and region, as some 3G networks are incredible well put together.

Hope that makes a little more sense for what you were asking.

Comment: I guess I didn't put across the question correctly. Here's what I'm trying to compare:

Wifi -> speed while communicating between two devices in same room vs speed while communicating between two devices in different cities.

3G -> same comparison (devices in same room vs 2 devices in different cities)

I'm not trying to compare Wifi vs 3G. Sorry for the confusing wording.

Comment: Ah my apologies. I will mull on how I can rewrite my answer to be specific.

Comment: An additional example of local wifi vs wifi to remote host. Local wifi between two computers can transfer gigs of data in a relative short amount of time. But the can't be said for connecting over a VPN (virtual private network) and sending a file to a remote host via wifi, which can run into hours on slow connection speeds.